# Custom Painter doesn't work. White screen appears instead

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to create background design using CustomPainter() but instead I am getting a white screen on my emulator.

I tried to apply purple color as backgroundColor using Scaffold() and it works but unable to get anything using CustomPainter.

My code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Background()));

class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint(painter: PurplePainter()));
  }
}
class PurplePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final height = size.height;
    final width = size.width;
    Paint paint = Paint();
    Path mainBackground = Path();
    mainBackground.addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, width, height));
    paint.color=Colors.purple.shade700;
    canvas.drawPath(mainBackground, paint);

    Path arcCreator = Path();
    arcCreator.moveTo(0, height*0.2);
    arcCreator.quadraticBezierTo(width*0.45, height*0.25, width*0.5, height*0.5);
    arcCreator.quadraticBezierTo(width*0.5, height*0.5, width*0.1, height);
    paint.color=Colors.purple.shade600;
    canvas.drawPath(arcCreator, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PurplePainter oldDelegate){
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

Could you able to help me out?

Comment: `CustomPaint(painter: PurplePainter(), child: SizedBox.expand(),)`

Answer (score 2):

On your `CustomPaint` widget, you can pass a `size` and a `painter` in order to render it on the screen. The default `size` of `CustomPaint` is `0.0`. In yours, you only have a `painter`, but did not give it `size`. You can give it either through the `size` parameter or a `child` widget. Simply do this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint(
        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size, //add this part
        painter: PurplePainter()),
    );
  }
```